# NodeHandle and ROS_DEBUG

Tags: ros, roscpp, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS members.

I had a trouble to use ROS_DEBUG macro after destructing a private node handle in a local scope.

As the following codes, when the "priv_nh1" node handle in the 1st local scope was
destructed, ROS_DEBUG macro will never say anything at all.
it's occurred in ROS::Groovy and ROS::Indigo.

In other words, the 1st and 2nd local scopes are meaning multi-threads or functions.

Is there bettwer way to use private node handles in each scopes?

Thank you.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/console.h>
int main( int  argc, char**  argv )
{
  ros::init( argc, argv, "test" );
  ROS_INFO("hello");
  { // <1st local scope>
    ROS_INFO("local scope : enter");
    ros::NodeHandle  priv_nh1("~");
    /* ... do something ... */
    ROS_INFO("local scope : exit");
  } // </1st local scope>
  // I can not get following ROS_DEBUG messages ...
  ROS_INFO("next");
  { // <2nd local scope>
    ROS_INFO("local scope : enter");
    ros::NodeHandle  priv_nh2("~");
    int              value = 0;
    priv_nh2.param( "value", value, 0 );
    ROS_INFO("value %d", value);
    ROS_INFO("local scope : exit");
  } // </2nd local scope>
  ROS_INFO("bye");
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187209/nodehandle-and-ros_debug/) by [ST-Lab](https://answers.ros.org/users/18291/st-lab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-07-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-21**:
Does ROS_DEBUG work if you use it elsewhere in your program?

**Comment by [ST-Lab](https://answers.ros.org/users/18291/st-lab/) on 2014-07-21**:
Thank you, ahendrix.
ROS_DEBUG can work anywhere, if I do not use such a private(disposable) node handle.
When I remove such a private node handle and get parameters by ros::param::get directly, there is no problem occurred.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-21**:
I'm seeing this with all of the rosconsle output macros, including ROS_INFO, not just ROS_DEBUG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The trouble here is that you don't have a persistent NodeHandle throughout the scope of your program.

As explained on the [NodeHandle wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/NodeHandles), once all NodeHandles go out of scope, the internal node is shut down.

Private NodeHandles with limited scope are generally a good idea, but you should also maintain a NodeHandle (public or private) that lasts for the entire duration of your program.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ST-Lab](https://answers.ros.org/users/18291/st-lab/) on 2014-07-21**:
Dear, ahendrix. Thank you for your advice. I've read the class reference of the node handle, and I also got the same conclution as well as you. The problem is based on the complexity of the global reference counter in the node handle. But I hope that the above made codes clean and safe.